# Jquery get Fancy box image index

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have integrated the fancybox slider with previous and next arrows in my site.

I want to open the slider while clicking the separate link. For this i used the following code

```
$('a.fancybox').eq(0).trigger('click'); return false;
```

It works fine. But it opens with the first image.

What i need is

The fancy box shows the 2nd image(By clicking the next arraow). At that time i click the text link to open the fancy box. it needs to shows up the 2nd image. For this i need to pass the index instead of 0 in the following code ` $('a.fancybox').eq(0).trigger('click'); return false;

Fot this i used the code

```
$('a.fancybox').eq($(this).index(this)).trigger('click'); return false;
```

But it didnt work.

How to get the current image index and how to pass this in the separate text link.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you want to do but check out the docs: http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs You can probably make use of the api methods or callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have different element of a gallery like

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

etc... and use the regular script to `bind` them to fancybox like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

Then you could have different *triggers* for `each` item in separated links like

```
<a href="#" class="triggers">trigger one</a>
<a href="#" class="triggers">trigger two</a>
```

etc.

... and then you just `bind` each *trigger* to fire the corresponding image in fancybox like :

```
$(".triggers").each(function (i) {
    $(this).bind("click", function () {
        $(".fancybox").eq(i).click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AmURs/)**